# No APSB22-48 patches for Magento 2.3

Tags: security, magento2, patch

We are still running Magento community version 2.3.4x.
We are upgrading since 4 months to current version, there were many plug-ins not compatible and so on.
Now we are about 2-3 weeks before we can fully switch.

On 11. of Oct. Adobe released:

```
Security update available for Adobe Commerce | APSB22-48
```

https://helpx.adobe.com/security/products/magento/apsb22-48.html

But our version of out of service since one month.

So we can not switch now, and there is also no patch.

```
Adobe Commerce 2.4.5 and earlier versions
```

What can we do until then?

I know this is not an adequate question here, but since It will probably affect 60% of all Shop worldwide, it's necessary to ask this here.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this: https://github.com/EmicoEcommerce/Magento-APSB22-48-Security-Patches

> This repository contains Magento 2 Patch Files for the recently found security issues on 12-10-2022. The patch files aim to fix the CVE-2022-35698 and CVE-2022-35689 vulnerabilities.

Comment: Rolled these out on 2.4.3-p2 commerce and 2.4.3-p3 open source without issue.